# Rails Active Model Serializer include in controller not injecting has many relationship in included parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, json-api

I'm seeing a strange behaviour regarding rails 5, active model serializer and the json-api adapter.

Given the following *User* model with the *Rolify* gem:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #
  # Gem Includes
  #
  rolify


  # Include devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  #
  # Callbacks
  #
  after_create :assign_default_role

  #
  # Attributes
  #
  attr_accessor :remote_image

  #
  # Validations
  #
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {in: 1..100}
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: {in: 1..100}
  validates :role_ids, presence: true, on: :update

  #
  # Relations
  #
  belongs_to :current_scenario, class_name: "Scenario"


  #
  # Private Instance Methods
  #
  def assign_default_role
    self.add_role(:user) if self.roles.blank?
  end

end
```

and the following controller code:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  authorize @user
  render json: @user, include: ['roles'], status: :ok
end
```

As you can see, I'm including the roles relationship to be rendered as part of the json api response, with json-api adapter format.

FYI, the *UserSerializer*:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  #
  # Attributes
  #
  attributes :id, :email, :name, :last_name, :image_url, :image_thumb_url, :created_at, :updated_at, :current_scenario_id, :last_sign_in_at

  #
  # Relations
  #
  has_one :current_scenario
  has_many :roles

  #
  # Methods
  #
  def image_url
    object.image_url
  end

  def image_thumb_url
    object.image_url(:thumb)
  end
end
```

When retrieving the json response, I get the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id":"2",
    "type":"users",
    "attributes": {
      "email":"talvarez@igaltex.com.ar", ...
    },
    "relationships": {
      "current-scenario": {
        "data": {
          "id":"204",
          "type":"scenarios"
        }
      },
      "roles": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id":1,
            "name":"user",
            "resource-type":null,
            "resource-id":null,
            "created-at":"2017-01-23T10:27:08.707-03:00",
            "updated-at":"2017-01-23T10:27:08.707-03:00"
          },
          {
            "id":2,
            "name":"admin",
            "resource-type":null,
            "resource-id":null,
            "created-at":"2017-01-24T09:40:53.020-03:00",
            "updated-at":"2017-01-24T09:40:53.020-03:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the included relationship roles with all its attributes is inside the *relationships* fragment of the json-api response. Shouldn't the roles data be inside the *included* fragment, which by the way is missing? Moreover inside the relationship fragment *roles* should appear only as a reference like: `{relationships: {roles: [{id: "1", type: "role"}, {id: "2", type: "role"}]}` am I wrong?

To contrast this, look what happens when also including the `current_scenario` relationship:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id":"2",
    "type":"users",
    "attributes": {
      "email":"talvarez@igaltex.com.ar",
      "name":"Tomás",
      "last-name":"Alvarez", 
      ...
    },
    "relationships": {
      "current-scenario": {
        "data": {
          "id":"204",
          "type":"scenarios"
        }
      },
      "roles": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id":1,
            "name":"user",
            "resource-type":null,
            ...
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "included": [
      {
        "id":"204",
        "type":"scenarios",
        "attributes": {
          "name":"Scenario reload II",
          "description":null,
          "created-at":"2017-04-18T11:55:35.242-03:00",
          "updated-at":"2017-04-18T11:55:35.242-03:00"
        },
        "relationships": {
          "scenario-stocks": {
            "data":[]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See how now the included fragment appears with all the information about current_scenario and only the reference to current_scenario is added to the *relationships* fragment. Is this because roles is a *has_many* relationship in the active model serializer while *current_scenario* is a *belongs_to* ? Am I understanding wrong the json-api adapter specification?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch. The inconsistency in the `JSON-API` response was because i forgot to add a Role model serializer in the backend side (Rails 5). This is the json response now, which is what i was looking for:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
        "email": "talvarez@igaltex.com.ar",
        "name": "Tomás",
        "last-name": "Alvarez",
        "image-url": "http://localhost:3001/uploads/user/image/2/05a4dc7.jpg",
        "image-thumb-url": "http://localhost:3001/uploads/user/image/2/thumb_05a4dc7.jpg",
        "created-at": "2017-01-23T10:39:12.485-03:00",
        "updated-at": "2017-04-25T16:32:14.610-03:00",
        "current-scenario-id": 204,
        "last-sign-in-at": "2017-04-25T16:29:03.559-03:00"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "current-scenario": {
            "data": {
                "id": "204",
                "type": "scenarios"
            }
        },
        "roles": {
            "data": [{
                "id": "1",
                "type": "roles"
            }, {
                "id": "2",
                "type": "roles"
            }]
        }
    }
},
"included": [{
    "id": "204",
    "type": "scenarios",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "Scenario reload II",
        "description": null,
        "created-at": "2017-04-18T11:55:35.242-03:00",
        "updated-at": "2017-04-18T11:55:35.242-03:00"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "scenario-stocks": {
            "data": []
        }
    }
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "roles",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "user"
    }
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "roles",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "admin"
    }
}]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this bug.  We haven't figured out how to determine the type for a relationship when no serializer is found. Would it have been more helpful if you got an exception?

Comment: Sure, with an exception i would've immediately noticed that i forgot to add a serializer and fix the bug pretty quickly.

Answer (score -1):

This is how `JSON API` works you can not retrieve desired model + relationship in 'one object'. Relationships always are separated. So you need to 'glue' it somehow. You can use [gem](https://github.com/chingor13/json_api_client) that can help you with it, or you can do it on front end side (all big frameworks support it). 
In general this approach with 'relationships' looks weird, but when you have complex object with tons of dependencies, this is the only one way that works.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The question was, why for current_scenario, when using *include: ['current_scenario']*, in the json response from the controller, all its data was added to the *included* fragment in the json response, but the same did not happen when including 'roles'.

Comment: Found the answer @nautgrad. Check my answer above, i will accept it tomorrow when stackoverflow allows me to.